# How to get a box to drop down and show links when clicked on?

Tags: list-view, css, html, dropdown, cascading

I have 6 boxes that are corresponding to different facets of IT. For example, if I click on a box that is based on CyberSecurity, how do I make it to where there are 3 links that will drop down from the box and shows 3 more branches of CyberSecurity? Would this have more to do with CSS/HTML? As you can tell I have not done something like this before.

Comment: Can you explain where you are trying to implement it ? Is it inside a SharePoint Page (page content,web parts) ?

Answer (score 0):

Is this in the navigation? It is possible to use managed metadata in order to create a drop down list. I'm using it in my current project. I created a term set in term-set management corresponding to the hierarchy of organization, set it as "use for navigation" then selected it under the navigation options in site settings.

Use managed metadata then select term store.

Hope that helps.